How to fix 'nan.h' : No such file or directory in nodejs addon?
I'm trying to create a BluetoothSerialPort nodejs addon.
I imported DeviceINQ.h to my BluetoothSerialPort.cc file.
When using npm install to install a Node.js addon I got this error:

DeviceINQ.h(17,10): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir  le fichier
include : 'nan.h' : No such file or directory
[C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Documents\bluetoothNodeJS\build\BluetoothSerialPort.vcxproj]

the problem with this line:

#include <nan.h>

The DeviceINQ.h code:
#ifndef NODE_BTSP_SRC_DEVICE_INQ_H
#define NODE_BTSP_SRC_DEVICE_INQ_H

#include <node.h>
#include <uv.h>
#include <nan.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#import <Foundation/NSArray.h>
#endif

struct bt_device {
    char address[19];
    char name[248];
};

#ifndef __APPLE__
struct bt_inquiry {
    int num_rsp;
    bt_device *devices;
};
#endif

class DeviceINQ : public Nan::ObjectWrap {
    private:
#ifdef _WIN32
        bool initialized;

        bool GetInitializedProperty() {
            return initialized;
        }
#endif

    public:
#ifdef _WIN32
        __declspec(property(get = GetInitializedProperty)) bool Initialized;
#endif
        static void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports);
        static void EIO_SdpSearch(uv_work_t *req);
        static void EIO_AfterSdpSearch(uv_work_t *req);
#ifdef __APPLE__
        static NSArray *doInquire();
#else
        static bt_inquiry doInquire();
#endif

    private:
        struct sdp_baton_t {
            DeviceINQ *inquire;
            uv_work_t request;
            Nan::Callback* cb;
            int channelID;
            char address[40];
        };

        DeviceINQ();
        ~DeviceINQ();

        static NAN_METHOD(New);
        static NAN_METHOD(Inquire);
        static NAN_METHOD(InquireSync);
        static NAN_METHOD(SdpSearch);
        static NAN_METHOD(ListPairedDevices);

};

#endif


<nan.h> and <nan> are not part of Standard C++ see C++ Standard Library headers.  I would suggest you raise a issue with the library maintainers.  Perhaps you are missing a dependancy?

Please remove the "c" tag, and add the commandline used for compiling. There's also a bunch of OS-specific code, which of that actually applies? Please provide a [mcve]!

@RichardCritten
where do i get the <nan.h> library
is nan a Native Abstractions for Node.js?

nan.h comes from a third-party library, which you either don't have, or your header search path doesn't cover it. Keep in mind that compilers don't search your entire system for files that might work -- they have a list of search locations, and options to add more directories yourself. It will only find files that are covered by this.

@RichardCritten nodejs has alrady https://github.com/nodejs/nan
I tried npm install --save nan and it did not work.

@DevM If you have the file nan.h already (and you should check) then the issue is simply that you have not told the compiler where to find nan.h. So look for nan.h and then alter your project settings to include that location when it searches for header files.

I just added to the binding.gyp file this:
"include_dirs" : [
    "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
]

